# "selected" attribute on select option being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this small piece of code (already processed by Angular).

```
<select data-ng-disabled="dataToRead.isReadonly"
    id="element-edit-details-modal-widget-select"
    data-ng-options="item for item in dataToRead.typeList"
    data-ng-model="dataToWrite.type"
    class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope"
    disabled="disabled">
  <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Section">Section</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, `selected` attribute is ignored, until... I change label or text contained by option in "Inspect element" window.

Until that the select box is empty.